# ASP.NET MVC REST frameworks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

There are number of REST frameworks around for ASP.NET MVC. Which one is the most mature in your opinion? Following are few I briefly looked at, but I couldn't decide.

1. [Snooze](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/snooze)
2. [BistroMVC](http://bistroframework.org/index.php?title=Bistro_Framework_Home)
3. [Restful Service with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529)
4. [OpenRasta](http://openrasta.org)
5. [Siesta](http://kohari.org/2009/08/10/siesta-painless-rest-via-asp-net-mvc/)
6. [REST support build in ASP.Net MVC SDK](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/04/17/developing-restful-services-with-json-and-pox-support-in-the-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

.... there are few more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would go with the default ASP.NET routing engine which is built and supported by Microsoft. This will ensure that you won't find yourself one day into the position of having to migrate some code which has become obsolete because the authors simply decided to abandon the project. Of course if there is something specific that you want to implement which isn't supported out of the box you could search for alternatives. But as far as exposing a RESTful API is concerned the routing engine should work just fine.

Comment: No one ever got fired for choosing Microsoft. RESTful APIs have very little to do with uri mappings anyway, and frameworks like OpenRasta provides their own routing engine.

Comment: I thought no one got fired for choosing IBM.... at least that's what they used to say. :p

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Darin.

But if you're looking for something closer to what WCF offers (Web service, versus a typical Web site), I've been extremely happy with WCF REST.

There's a WCF REST Service Template available via Visual Studio's Extension Manager that will get you up and running fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

OpenRasta

Have been implementing RESTFul service using OR, only one word to describe it => "Pure Awesomeness" ....actually it's 2 words.

For me the simplicity is a plus, the framework is easy to use and adopt to. Some of it's conventions in my opinion really help me to understand Resful. Many integration points in the framework, very easy to extend its functionalists.

watching video recordings of seb's talk is very entertaining as well :) very opinionated (in a good way IMO)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Darin. Personally, I think [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) is also an option for doing client and server communication.