# What type of ASP.NET Webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I need some advice here.
I need to make a webservice, that can make a simple query into my database, from any C# project.
Basically, I'm looking up an itemnumber, and returning the itemname.

It looks like WCF Data Services are really cool, but I'm not really sure it makes sense in my case. From what I have read, they are good for browsing datasets, where I just want to return 1 string.

But, at the same time, I don't want to use obsolete services, or services that are dying. From what I can tell, the good old ASP.NET Webservice (ashx) seems to fall into that category.

So, my question is, what type of webservice should I use?

Comment: REST seems popular nowadays - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769973/asp-net-mvc-rest-frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [standard WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) (not WCF Data Services).