# Calling Codebehind .cs file method in Javascript method in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to do the page level validation in javascript for and element and if the validation is passed i want to call the codebehind method .cs file method of .aspx.cs file method. 
Can anyone please provide any details / code which will make this requirement work in an easy way. 
I am trying to do this in C# .net. 
Thanks,

Comment: what have you done so far.?

Comment: Have you read anything on form validation in ASP.NET?  Learn what is offered in the .NET Framework, and you'll find what you need.

Comment: is there are way by which we can call it without jquery?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is possible...in a direct and easy way. Javascript code is client-side, cs codebehind is server side code.

Usually, the way to "use", or "access" .NET code and methods you need from Javascript (but this applies in general to server-side code) is to expose these methods as a service. Possibly, a REST service or a web-service. See WCF and other frameworks (e.g. ServiceStack) on how to create it. I particularly like ServiceStack; it is simple to use and gets things done in a minute!

A useful list can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769973/asp-net-mvc-rest-frameworks)